# When casting Thaumaturgy, is the verbal component what you wish to say?

Tags: cantrips

The Thaumaturgy cantrip requires verbal activation, and one of its effects is to make the voice about 3 times louder than normal. because of this, could the verbal activation be what you say, if it is meant to be used quickly for a sort of dramatic intimidation

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about? Please include a tag to indicate this. There are thousands of RPGs and we can't provide an answer without knowing which one the question is about.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As Purple Monkey says, we need to know the RPG and edition you're asking about in order to help you. You can indicate this by editing the appropriate tag (e.g. [dnd-5e] or [pathfinder-2e]) into your post. Once you do that, we can reopen and answer your question, or point out where it has already been answered. Hope you stick around! :)